# Factory boy's post_generation hook is not setting attribute on the model object after upgrading Django to 2.2

Tags: django, factory-boy

Consider the case of following two factories. Some part of the code might not make sense as I've tried to anonymise classes and fields.

```py
class FactoryA(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA

    name = 'John'

    @factory.post_generation
    def post_hook(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        post_generated_objs = []
        for i in range(3):
            post_generated_objs.append(SomeOtherFactory(id=i+100))
        self.post_generated_objs = post_generated_objs
        return post_generated_objs
```

```py
class FactoryB(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB

    some_data = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: obj.model_a.post_generated_objects[0])
```

It used to work as expected before upgrading Django to latest version, i.e. 2.2. I am using latest version of factoryboy as well. The issue here is that factoryboy is not setting the attribute `post_generated_objs` to the returned object of `ModelA` created by `FactoryA`.

The error I get is `AttributeError: 'ModelA' object has no attribute 'post_generated_objs'`

```
Python 3.7

django==2.2.4
factory-boy==2.12.0
pytest==4.4.0
pytest-django>=3.5
pytest-xdist==1.28.0
```

Comment: You need to provide some more details: how does `FactoryB` get its `model_a` pointer? How do you call `FactoryB` in your test? When you call `FactoryA` directly, do you get the expected attribute?

Comment: Yes I do get the expected attribute when I directly call `FactoryA`.

Comment: OK, so the issue might be in the way you've defined `model_a` on `FactoryB`; can you describe that part?

Comment: Hi here's a gist on the 3 factories that are involved. This should be explanatory enough. Thanks for taking your time to explore this issue.
https://gist.github.com/debugger22/6219b92a36244dcb4a4a6469458dd706

Comment: @Xelnor did you get time to see the gist?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like a bug. Could you open an issue on https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues with those details? It would be a better place for tracking that :)

Comment: I've already done that. I'll post the gist as well.

Comment: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/640